# How to set environment variable in EC2 Instance for a node app

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently running a node application on an EC2 Instance Linux using PM2 to manage and it keeps crashing, throwing an error that reads `Username is required`.

This username is being fed from `process.env.USERNAME` that I set using dotenv for development.

So far using AWS shell I have tried to pass the env variable in the following paths:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile.d
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
```

The variables were put in this form: `export VARIABLE_KEY=VALUE`

I also tried to put the variables inside `/etc/environment`. None of which is making it work.

I restarted the server each time, logged out, and logged back in.

Comment: if i understood correctly you want to set env variable for your  node application or is it for your instance?

Comment: Whatever you are experiencing would not be specific to it being an Amazon EC2 instance. It is the operating system that controls environment variables.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes, I want to set the env variable for the node application. meanwhile on "printenv",  the system lists all my env variables but my node app is just not picking them up when running

Comment: I have posted a solution which i follow.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Thanks for the thought, but that wouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: will it wont solve even if you use.gitignore to ignore which files needs to committed ?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I currently have a .env file locally, I'm also running a CI/CD from gitlab to  my EC2 Instance, which automatically exempts the file from being deployed to EC2. I would think that for security reasons, it might not be a good idea to commit the .env file or have it living on the server. wouldn't you think so too?

Comment: Now i got it that you are using a CI/CD, let me come up with something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226163/discussion-between-jatin-mehrotra-and-victor-ofrank).

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved it was to restart pm2 using `pm2 restart --update-env`. When you first run `pm2 start`, it caches the env variables, so I needed to restart it to add the newly created env variables.